# Azure WebJob: stop trigger when create/overwrite a blob in the same container

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

i have a webjob that resize and overwrites the same image in the blob container. How can i prevent the webjob from triggering again on the same file? i'm using the imageresizer library btw

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessBlob(
        [BlobTrigger("media/{filename}")] Stream input,
        [Blob("media/{filename}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream output,
        string filename,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("blob path: {0}", filename);
        var instructions = new Instructions
        {
            Width = 1920,
            Mode = FitMode.Max,
            Scale = ScaleMode.DownscaleOnly,
            JpegQuality = 80
        };
        ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(input, output, instructions));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive method needs an exit condition.

The simplest solution is to write converted files to a different container, ex `media-resized`:

```
public static void ProcessBlob(
    [BlobTrigger("media/{filename}")] Stream input,
    [Blob("media-resized/{filename}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream output,
    string filename,
    ILogger logger) { ... }
```

Alternative is to write to the same container but to a different file with a recognizable suffix (ex: `{filename}.1920px.jpg`) and add condition to your function to stop processing files with that suffix.

Should you really-really want in-place upgrade then you could also [set custom "converted" marker in blob metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata#setting-and-retrieving-metadata) on conversion and let the function check it before conversion to avoid recursion.

Note that for the last 2 options you most likely need to bind to `CloudBlockBlob` instead of `Stream`. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---usage) for options.